# Port Javascript application on Windows/iOS/Android etc

Tags: javascript, android, ios, windows

I have developed a small JavaScript game and I'd like to extend it outside webbrowser, making desktop and mobile versions available. What is the best way to do so reutilizing existing JavaScript code?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is to make use of Phonegap. See the [PhoneGap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/index.html). It supports [the mobile Platforms](http://phonegap.com/about/feature/).